# How do I save user input to a txt document?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to create a simple `.txt` file  that is taking input from text boxes in a windows form

I am trying to create a 2 line text script that takes me at work to copy and paste all the different pieces.

I have the form designed and all the text boxes label, but I need help with what the code will be to take the information from the user input and generate a `txt` file upon a button click event.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? Right now the only "Acceptable" answer would be writing your whole program for you. Can you please explain what you have tried, and what step you are stuck on, so we can help you learn how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
string saveText = textbox1.text;

System.IO.File.WriteAlltext("savePath",saveText);
```

it is very simlpe way

Answer (score 0):

You should put the following code to the button click event:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("yourfilename.txt");
sr.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
sr.Close();
```

This code will take the textBox1.Text (which was entered by the user) and will output it into the file.
You will need to add `using System.IO` into the using part on the top of your code file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your textboxes are named `tb1` and `tb2`, and there is a button called `button1`, this should get you started:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string tb1Text = tb1.Text;
    string tb2Text = tb2.Text;

    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("myfile.txt")) {
       sw.WriteLine(tb1Text + Environment.NewLine + tb2Text);
    }
}
```

In this case the `button1_Click` method is the click handler for your button.

Also: if you are missing a reference (like to System.IO for StreamWriter), you can just do `Ctrl+.` (Control key & period key together), and Visual Studio will suggest the namespace to add, and add it for you.